# Finding the smallest number of steps between two points?

Tags: java, vb.net, algorithm, graph-algorithm

I have a grid, The Grid have two "Material" -

- Floor
- Wall

For example :

[image: This is An Example Of a Grid]
In this grid we have objects that have size and location (The location of an object is the top left point).

On each object we can do some action like -

- Move Up
- Move Down
- Move Left
- Move Right
- Turn The Object (Relative to the top left point)

I need to make a function that returns me the Minimum amount of actions I need to do on a object to move it from one point to another point (**I need only the amount of action**).

I solved this problem using [dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm), **but without the turn action**.

So can anyone help me to build this function.

Example of the problem -

- The starting point -
  [image]
- The end point

[image]

And I need to return the minimum amount of actions I need to do on a object.

Comment: It does not really matter which language (c++,c,vb.net,java,c#)

Comment: Hint: Think about the state of your object at any point in time.  There's more than just the usual (x, y) co-ords -- what else do you need to record?  The four directional moves each change either the x or y co-ord of the state; what will the turn move change?

Comment: The turn move will change the size of the object like this -                      
Size = Reverse(CurrenSize), Height=Width and Width=Height

Comment: What I mean is: Stop thinking of the vertices in the graph as literally representing all the *positions* in the maze; they represent all the *possible states* that the object can be in.  Part of an object state is its (top-left corner's) position, but that isn't *all* of it.

Comment: Can you give us more detail on the actions: apart from the direction, how much can you move? Is it fixed (like Move left -> increase `x` position of the top-left corner by `lambda`)? The same goes for the rotation. What are our options? It's gonna be "any rotation of k.q°, where k is an integer and q a fixed constant. Thus the question becomes: what is q?

Comment: Move Up - You will Move up one place (Y+1).       
Move left - You will Move left one place (X-1).      
Move Down - You will Move Down  one place (Y-1).       
Move Right - You will Move Right one place (x+1).      
Trun - It will Turn the object 90 degree, it mean you need to change the size of the object Height=Width and Width=Height.

Comment: Will the turn ever change the (X, Y) position? I mean, when the object is in vertical position, it will turn 90º counterclockwise, and when it is in horizontal position it will turn 90º clockwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your problem, I think BFS still works.

Using BFS to solve traditional Maze problem, starting from the beginning point, you have to:

```
1. Enqueue every point that is accessible (not a piece of wall, and not visited) and connected to the current point.
2. Dequeue current point and mark it as VISITED.
```

From above, you can see that BFS won't let any point to be visited twice, thus loop is avoided.

## Your Problem

As for your problem, BFS still works, but we will slightly change the definition of "accessible":

First, I will introduce what the "maze" matrix looks like.
Here is what the numbers mean in the following images.

(Assume that the size of the object is 1*2, and when moving, the top-left corner of the object stays at each point).

```
00: The point can't be accessed, neither the object is horizontal nor vertical. 
10: The point can be accessed if the object is horizontal
01: The point can be accessed if the object is vertical
11: The point can be accessed if the object is either horizontal or vertical
```

And your graph can be converted into a matrix like below:

[image: img1]

Fill in those inaccessible points with 00, and you'll get

[image]

This is more like a Maze problem, but a little bit different.

Finally, let's see how to "access" those points:

The definitions of `connected` is similar to the traditional Maze problem. Here are some examples:

```
---------
| 01| 10|
|---|---|
| 10|   |
---------    (Not Connected from top-left to either top-right or bottom-left)


---------
| 11| 10|
|---|---|
| 01|   |
---------    (Connected from top-left to both top-right and bottom-left)


---------
| 10| 10|
|---|---|
| 01|   |
---------    (Connected from top-left to top-right, but not connected to bottom-left)
```

So the rest may be simple. Follow the traditional BFS method, and create a 2-dimension array to store the length of the shortest path at each point. Dequeue to get the current point, add `connected` neighbors of current point to the queue, and mark this point as VISITED, then everything will be the same as BFS.

After you've got the shortest path, re-run your program, maintain a state of whether the object is vertical or horizontal at current point, and simulate your move on the image. Add turns only when necessary, and you will get the result with turns added.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Consider the problem as finding the shortest path in a 3D grid, with a depth of 2 (each of the possible states: horizontal and vertical). You have to code the constraints that disallows one from moving from one depth to another, e.g., cannot go vertical if it doesn't fit that way.

Now you can just use regular BFS to find the shortest path in a grid (i.e., an unweighted graph).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking, writing this out would take too long, but the easiest way of doing it I can think of is finding the path first, check for collision along that path, rotate, and add the actions accordingly.

- Use basic pathing algorithm to find the path to the end.
- Store path nodes in some sort of traversable array (should be 4 total if the pathing algorithm is good/simple).
- Attempt to follow path notes (i to array count)
- Check for collision on each movement.
- (do while) If movable object intersects with the wall, rotate 90 degrees and try again.
- (next) If success, save to move action list (move x/y, rotate z)
- Return action count

With a more complicated grid, this would obviously get more complicated, but you only have to do 90 degree turns. It should be possible in ~9 actions.

Answer (score -2):

Use the [Breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) strategy, assigning weights to edges depending on must turn the object or not.

Comment: There is a problem in this method, Because in the search we can get into loops, like Move Up,Down,Up,Down....

Comment: This won't work, because you don't know what orientation the object currently has -- it could be either.  -1.

Comment: It's much more complicated than that, the ability to rotate the object implies the object can be in different states while at the same position.